# Get count of each unique value in one column of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, unique, counting

I need to count the unique values in the first column of my 2d array.

Input:

```
[
    ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a', ''],
    ['c', 'a', 'd', '',  ''],
    ['b', 'd', 'a', '',  ''],
    ['a', 'd', 'c', 'b', '']
]
```

So far, I have this code:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($the_outer_array as $key=>$value) {
    if ($value [0] == 'c') {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

However, I can only check for one value at a time. Should I have an outer loop like `foreach(range('a','d') as $i)`?

Once the count is done, I am hoping to store the values in an array.

Desired result:

```
['b' => 2, 'c' => 1, 'a' => 1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) & increment the count,

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($the_outer_array as $key=>$value) {
    $firstValue = $value[0];
    if ($foundKey = array_key_exists($firstValue,$newArray)) {
        $newArray[$firstValue] += 1;
    }
   else{
        $newArray[$firstValue] = 1;
   }
}
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.org/djlVk4Oa)**

Answer (score 3):

In php 5.5 there are [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array-column) + [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array-count-values):

```
print_r(array_count_values(array_column($array, 0)));
```

*Example:*

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$array = [
    [ 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a' ],
    [ 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a' ],
    [ 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a' ]
];

print_r(array_count_values(array_column($array, 0)));
?>
```

*Results:*

```
Array
(
    [b] => 1
    [c] => 2
)
```