# array group by and count php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, logging

I have 2 log files which i read and get the contents as array.
The array which i get is like this:

```
2 => array:9 [▼
"app" => "a.log"
"context" => "local"
"level" => "error"
"level_class" => "danger"
"level_img" => "exclamation-triangle"
"date" => "2018-10-25 21:01:04"
"text" => "Class 'Arcanedev\Support\Collection' not found 
]
3 => array:9 [▼
"app" => "b.log"
"context" => "local"
"level" => "error"
"level_class" => "danger"
"level_img" => "exclamation-triangle"
"date" => "2018-10-26 16:49:07"
```

I need to get the count of all the error levels for each file.
For example:

```
a.log => "count of error level for a.log",
b.log => "count of error levels for b.log"
```

I have tried:

```
foreach($names as $filename){
            $logs = $this->getLogs($this->filepath.$filename);                
            $result = array();
            $result[ $filename ] = $logs;                
            foreach($logs as $log){
                //$result[ $log['level'] ][] = $log;
                $result[ $filename ][] = $log;
                $counts = array_map('count', $result);
            }
        }
```

which gives me this result:

```
array:1 [▼
   "a.log" => 20
]
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue myself. I was tried another approach and it seemed to work.
Here is the solution:

```
foreach($names as $filename){
   $logs = $this->getLogs($this->filepath.$filename);                
   $result = array();                
   foreach($logs as $log){                    
      $result[ $log['app'] ][] = $log;
      $counts = array_map('count', $result);
   }
}
```

and the result:

```
array:2 [▼
  "b-laravel.log" => 3
  "laravel.log" => 7
 ]
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
   print_r(array_count_values(array_column($array, 'app')));
```

I would test it but you didn't provide an array i can use.  In theory it should work.

Comment: Shown earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21250816/2943403)